# Grammars - Left recursion

Tags: recursion, grammar, left-recursion

I've a problem in understanding left recursion. I know that this is a left recursion: A->Aa
Can you tell me if this is left recursion? A->aA

And can you explain me why this is an indirect left recursion?

- D ---> dcD' | SD'
- D' --> DbaD' | DcD' | e

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you sure about the `S` in `D -> ... SD'` ?

Answer (score 1):

A grammar is left recursive if starting from a non terminal `E` and applying rules you find a string which start with `E` itself. If its a direct rule then it's direct left recursive as it `A- > Aa`. If you have to apply more rule then it's indirect.

I'm assuming you grammar is

```
- `D ---> dcD' | D'`
- `D' --> DbaD' | DcD' | e`
```

Then you have the derivation

```
 D -> D' -> DbaD'
```

So this in an indirect left recursion.

Now, if you are sure that there is an `S`, then it depends of what you can derive from `S`. But if there is no `D` at the beginning of any word deriving from `S`, then it is non left recursive.

By the way, this is better to ask those kind of question on  https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi, I'm sure that there's a "S". My friend told me that he was sure that it was a type of indirect left recursion, but I've studied a little more and now I'm almost sure that he's wrong. Can you confirm that if there's an "S" in the second rule of D (like in my text) we DON'T have indirect left recursion?

PS: thanks for the tip about stackexchange!